# Cannot Install Power Pivot in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, powerpivot

I have a **Windows 10 Enterprise** Citrix machine that has **Microsoft Office Excel 2013 Professional Plus** installed.

From **Excel** when I click  `File` > `Options` > `Add-Ins` I do not see a **Power Pivot** option.

[image]

I do see a **Power View** option and a few others but nothing pertinent to **Power Pivot**.

I got this error while trying to install an add-in:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 PowerPivot for Excel Setup  Setup is missing
>   prerequisites:  This add-in requires Excel 2010. If you have 32-bit
>   Excel, you must install the  32-bit version of ene add-in. If not, you
>   must install the 64-bit version.

Comment: What do you see then? Maybe a few screenshots could help.

Comment: Hi @MátéJuhász,just updated the question. Thank you.

Comment: @MátéJuhász,I did try your suggestion and please see updated question.

Comment: The message explains what your problem is and what you should do to resolve it.

Comment: @gronostaj Mine is SQL 2014.There is no specific Addin for excel which is working in my case.Only after I tried all options I reached Super User.

Comment: SQLBoy - This is actually a known problem with PowerPivot and Excel 2013. I added an answer below with multiple fixes so hopefully one of these will fix your problem. Be sure that you're on a version that supports this functionality as well... My answer has thorough detail on this with references, quoted step information and quick download links, etc. Do your research and be sure to do your backups too and especially with the registry editing steps but maybe the quick fix will resolve or you confirm you need to install from newer standalone for the feature to be available.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Please note that Excel 2013 PowerPivot functionality is built-in starting with editions 1511 unlike how it worked with the older 2010 version of Excel for example so Excel 2010 and 2013 and PowerPivot **DO NOT** work the same as far as being a separate entities... it's built-in functionality with Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerPivot Missing in Excel 2013 Fix

### As stated here. . .

> As you said you’re a home user, I suggest you buy a downloadable
>   version of Excel 2013 Standalone. If You Install Excel 2013
>   Standalone, and update to version 1511, you will get Power Pivot which
>   should happen automatically anyway.
>
> *More information about office versions with Power BI features please refer to this article.*
>
> *http://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2013/02/01/office-2013-office-365-editions-and-bi-features/*
>
> <sub>[source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4727a471-2cc1-41d8-a4a6-0d8b45626ac7/powerpivot-is-not-available-in-com-addins-in-excel-2013-professional?forum=officesetupdeploy)</sub>

You should confirm that your build of Excel 2013 is of the version 1511 or newer which includes this functionality to ensure you have a version where you can indeed use PowerPivot features.

### Solutions that have worked for others. . .

> We had the same issue, tried the registry fix but no luck. **We fixed
>   it** by going into *Control Panel > Programs and Features >
>   selecting Microsoft Office Pro Plus 2013 > selecting Change > Add or Remove Features > Continue > click the `+` next to Microsoft Excel `+`
>   Add-ins > drop down next to PowerPivot and selected Run from My
>   Computer > Continue* and then went back into Excel and it was now an
>   available add-in under com add-ins. Looks like the default
>   installation didnt install PowerPivot.
>
> <sub>[source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/22745f2d-2f93-4f52-8fc4-dc325cfb75d7/help-powerpivot-in-excel-2013-is-missing?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel)</sub>

---

> ### [**Fix it for me**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2805999/com-add-ins-are-not-displayed-in-the-com-add-ins-dialog-box-in-excel-2013-and-excel-2016)
>
> To resolve this issue, run the appropriate troubleshooter for the
>   add-in:
>
> **PowerPivot**
>
> - The PowerPivot add-in troubleshooter may automatically fix the problem described in this article.  This troubleshooter fixes many
>     problems.
>
>   [<kbd>**`run now`**</kbd>](http://aka.ms/easyfix20073)
> - The Power View add-in troubleshooter may automatically fix the problem described in this article.  This troubleshooter fixes many
>     problems.
>     [<kbd>**`run now`**</kbd>](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=279892)
>
> ---
>
> To work around this issue, follow these steps to delete the affected
>   registry keys:
>
> **Notes**
>
> - Excel 2013 and Excel 2016 automatically rebuilds the registry keys.
> - The registry keys that you have to delete vary, depending on the    add-ins that you use. You have to delete the registry keys only for the add-in that is missing from the COM Add-Ins dialog box. Each add-ins corresponds to the following registry keys, respectively:
>
> Microsoft Office PowerPivot for Excel 2013 add-in
>
> - **`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\User Settings\PowerPivotExcelAddin`**
> - **`KEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\PowerPivotExcelClientAddIn.NativeEntry.1`**
>
> Microsoft Office PowerPivot for Excel 2016 add-in
>
> - **`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\User Settings\PowerPivotExcelAddin`**
> - **`KEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\PowerPivotExcelClientAddIn.NativeEntry.1`**
>
> ---
>
> ### More Information
>
> **Important:** These add-ins and the Inquire add-in all require specific SKUs of Microsoft Office 2013 and Microsoft Office 2016. They
>   are available on:
>
> - Microsoft Office 2013 Professional Plus and Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016
> - Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus available as a standalone subscription.
> - Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus available as part of the Office 365 Enterprise E3, Office 365 Enterprise E4, Office 365 Education E2, Office 365 Education E3, Office 365 Government E3, or Office 365 Government E4 offerings.
> - Microsoft Excel 2013 standalone with the following update http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2817425
>
> <sub>[source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2805999/com-add-ins-are-not-displayed-in-the-com-add-ins-dialog-box-in-excel-2013-and-excel-2016)</sub>

---

### Further Resources

- [Microsoft has released an update for Microsoft Excel 2013. This update provides the latest fixes for the 32-bit and 64-bit editions of the standalone version of the Excel 2013 Full Packaged Product and Volume Licensing. Additionally, this update contains the COM add-ins of Power View and PowerPivot..](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2817425/description-of-the-excel-2013-update-august-13,-2013)
- [Start the Power Pivot in Microsoft Excel add-in](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Start-the-Power-Pivot-in-Microsoft-Excel-add-in-a891a66d-36e3-43fc-81e8-fc4798f39ea8?CorrelationId=7d5fdc5a-d7a3-4b7f-b620-2fee091f666c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102837097)

Comment: Hi @ https://superuser.com/users/510662/magicallydelicous,I will try this options.Some of them I already checked on,but still will go through your suggestions and will let you know.Thanks for your time and response.

Comment: @SQLBoy Feel free to accept my answer if you found it helpful in resolving your issue. I assume you already know how that works but see [Accepting An Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) just in case. Let me know if you need anything further though; I'm just following up and trying to close the loop.